# Face not getting tracked in Augmented faces using ARCore

Tags: android, c++, arcore

While using ArAugmented face, Arcore is tracking the face sporadically and no face is being tracked for a few moments intermittently though there are no changes in location of face and lighting. I printed trackable list size for these durations and it came out to be zero.

Firstly i tried using ArSession_getAllTrackables API and then by using ArFrame_getUpdatedTrackables API but still the ArTrackableList *out_trackable_list is empty (Basically ArTrackableList_getSize gives 0)

I am trying to implement this in NDK. Did anyone else also face the same issue?

```
    ArTrackableList_create(ar_session_, &out_trackable_list);

    ArSession_getAllTrackables(ar_session_, AR_TRACKABLE_FACE,out_trackable_list);

   ArTrackableList_getSize(ar_session_, out_trackable_list, &out_size);
```

Since the out_size is 0, I am not able to proceed further in rendering any model or mask on the face.

This happens in 6 out of 10 trials. But when it works, it works perfectly.